# Python Variable Access

Tags: python, variables, instance

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.i = 0
    def demo(self):
        self.a=1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, j = 0):
        super().__init__()
        self.j = j
        print(self.i)
        self.demo()
    def demo(self):
        print(self.a)

def main():
    b = B()
    print(b.i)
    print(b.j)
main()
```

why am i not able to access self.a inside class b
does prefixing a variable with self. will make it an instance variable
Thanks

Comment: As question was already anwsered I would only like to point that in almost every case you SHOULD declare all instance parameters in __init__, even with simple `self.a = None`. Fist - you will never get `AttributeError`, second - you will have cleaner code with all your instance variables declared in the same place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you include a `demo` method for both classes, the most recently-defined one masks the others. Since you define `B` after you define `A` but before you call any of the methods in `A`, `demo` will try to access a variable that was never defined. You should either call `demo` within `A` (in `__init__`, probably), or change the name of `demo` in `B` to something unique, which will allow you to access both methods (probably the best approach, since they do different things and you want to make use of both).

Comment: Thanks what will be the scope of variable a is that instance or local

Comment: It is an instance variable, as its reference is `self.a`.

Comment: Note that calling `self.demo()` in `A` wouldn't address the issue, since it'd still get `B.demo`. If you were to go with that route, you'd need to explicitly invoke `A.demo(self)`. I'd say using different names is a better solution, but the code is contrived enough and has enough other design issues that it's hard to talk about what it "should" do.

Answer (score 1):

Because you overwrite `demo` method on `B class`.
If you want to access `self.a` add it to `__init__` method of `A` class or  call parent `demo` method like this:

```
   def demo(self):
       super().demo()
       print(self.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because instance variable `b` is not initiated within `__init__` of `A`

Answer (score 0):

Because class A.demo() is not executed:
    class A:
        def **init**(self):
            self.i = 0
        def demo(self):
            self.a=1

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, j = 0):
        super().__init__()
        self.j = j
        print(self.i)
        super().demo()
        self.demo()
    def demo(self):
        print(self.a)

def main():
    b = B()
    print(b.i)
    print(b.j)

main()
```